# white box between scroll wheels

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am having a bit of a CSS styling problem with an analytics dashboard that I am setting up. I've got the styling right for the table and scrollbars, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get rid of the white square in the bottom right hand corner of my table. I know that I can get rid of the horizontal scrollbar and that should fix the issue, however I need the scroll overflow in case there are long strings.

Relevant CSS:

```
.keen-dataviz-table {
  border-bottom: 0px!important;
}

.keen-dataviz-table::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

.keen-dataviz-table::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.keen-dataviz-table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

The chart HTML is generated by Keen.io, the only HTML I have on my page for this is the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div id="chart-01"></div>
  <br>
</div>
```

I've attached an image below for reference (please ignore the silly intents, I was just stress-testing some NLP intents/entities and the horizontal overflow of this table).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Example of CSS Styling issue]

Comment: provide html and css

Comment: No one can read this. Please edit your question and do not post code in a comment.

Comment: @tavkomann i've updated the original question to include the code for future reference as it has now been answered.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can style the scroll corner with the scrollbar cornet selector

```
.keen-dataviz-table::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   background: red;
  }
```

```css
table {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 1499px;
  overflow:auto;
 
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
   background: red;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```